# Geolocation based List Sorting

Tags: jquery, mobile, geolocation

I have a list in jquery mobile. I have added code to resort the list based on the nearest state I am in. For some reason, my logic does not work. Any ideas why? Also the list is very sluggish when scrolling.

Check this link out and click Find Nearest Location Button on Top Left

http://www.jm.bugs3.com/gl/state.html

```
<script>
function findMe(){

    if (navigator.geolocation !=undefined){
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onFound, handleError);
    }
}
function onFound(position){
    var userLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var userLong = position.coords.longitude;
    $('ul li').each(function (index){
        var locationLat = $(this).find('.lat').html();
        var locationLong = $(this).find('.long').html();
        var distance = getDistance(userLat, locationLat, userLong, locationLong);
        $(this).data("distance", distance);
    })

    reOrder();  
}



function handleError(error){
    alert ("Could not find location");
}

function reOrder(){
    $('ul li').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('ul');  
}

function sortAlpha(a, b){
    return $(a).data('distance') > $(b).data('distance') ? 1 : -1;  //if True or false 1 or -1
};
//Calculate the shortest distance based on lat and long
function getDistance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2){
    var R = 6371; //KM
    var d = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) +
            Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon2 - lon1)) * R
        return d    
};
```

// Here is the code for the list with lat and long coordinates

```
<div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li>
                <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" >Alabama</a>
                <div class="lat" style="visibility:hidden">31.375626</div>
                <div class="long" style="visibility:hidden">-86.299592</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#page3" data-transition="slide">Alaska</a>
                <div class="lat" style="visibility:hidden">60.216736</div>
                <div class="long" style="visibility:hidden">-149.882995</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#page4" data-transition="slide">Arizona</a>
                <div class="lat" style="visibility:hidden">32.447659</div>
                <div class="long" style="visibility:hidden">-112.134568</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#page5" data-transition="slide" >Arkansas</a>
                <div class="lat" style="visibility:hidden">33.678252</div>
                <div class="long" style="visibility:hidden">-92.340846</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#page6" data-transition="slide" >Boston</a>
                <div class="lat" style="visibility:hidden">41.358431</div>
                <div class="long" style="visibility:hidden">-71.059773</div>
            </li>
```

Comment: That link is dead. Doesn't open here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hershey,

"... based on the nearest state I am in" is a tad difficult to interpret for the following reasons :

- At its simplest, "the nearest state I am in" is "the state I am in"
- "The nearest geographic centre of a state" may not be that of "the state I am in" (eg. if I am at the western end of the Florida Pan Handle, then the "nearest state" is Alabama, not Florida)
- I might not be in a state (eg. I am at sea).

Notwithstanding this difficulty and trusting that your own code correctly reflects the proper meaning, and working from @ddotsenko's answer as a startpoint, then the following improvements might be made :

- A true sort operation can be avoided by loading `<li>` references into an array, rather than an object, indexed by distance (rounded). This will give a sparse array in the correct order.
- The `<li>` elements can be reordered within their original `<ul>` avoiding the need for a new `<ul>` element at each sort.

Taking these points onboard, a modified version of ddotsenko's code would be as follows:

```
function onFound(position) {
    var userLat = position.coords.latitude,
        userLong = position.coords.longitude,
        arr = [],
        $ul = $("ul");//a more specific selector would be good
    $ul.find('li').each(function (index) {
        var $this = $(this),
            lat = Number($this.data("latitude")),
            lng = Number($this.data('longitude')),
            dist = Math.round(getDistance(userLat, lat, userLong, lng));
        arr[dist] = this;
    });
    //At this point, arr is a sparse array of li elements indexed by distance, hence in distance order.
    for(var item in arr) {
        //Ref: "Iterating over sparse arrays", //http://hexmen.com/blog/2006/12/iterating-over-sparse-arrays/
        if (String(item >>> 0) == item && item >>> 0 != 0xffffffff) {
            $ul.append(item);
        }
    };
}
```

This should be appreciably faster.

Regarding, sluggish scrolling, you may be better off with less elements in the DOM. The javasctipt in ddotsenko's code indicates `<li>s` of the following format :

```
<li data-latitude="31.375626" data-longitude="-86.299592">
    <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" >Alabama</a>
</li>
```

which should be better than hidden divs to hold the data.

Even better would be to have all the lat/long pairs hard-coded in javascript, thus avoiding slower retreival from the DOM, eg.:

```
var stateLocations = {
    "Alabama":  {lat: 31.375626, lng: -86.299592},
    "Alaska":   {lat: 60.216736, lng: -149.882995},
    "Arizona":  {lat: 32.447659, lng: -112.134568},
    "Arkansas": {lat: 33.678252, lng: -92.340846},
    ...
};
```

Then look up accordingly.

*By the way, Boston is a city, not a state. None of the United States begins with "B"*

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's sort is O(n) - in other words, it touches each element more than one time. This means you do .data( calls many times over same elem and you move it multiple times as well, triggering browser redraw each time.

Don't sort the elements, sort its "distance" array.

Then, remove whole UL from view,
iterate over the distance array,
map each value back to LI
pluck it from original UL,
append it to new UL.
Put new UL in place of old UL.

This way browser redraw happens only once and you use already-computed values (as opposed to digging into elem attrs) within sort function.

Also, using data attr is faster than .find('div with class') to pull lat, lon.

The below does not hide / show old / new UL, which means you get redraw after each LI is moved, but the amount of backend calculations is much reduced.

```
var distance_to_li_map = {}
$('ul li').each(function (index){
    var $this = $(this)
    , locationLat = $this.data("latitude")
    , locationLong = $this.data('longitude')
    , distance = getDistance(userLat, locationLat, userLong, locationLong)

    // store LI elem pointers into map
    distance_to_li_map[distance] = this
})

var distances = Object.keys(distance_to_li_map)

distances.sort()

var newUL = $('<ul></ul>').insertBefore('ul' /*the old UL*/)[0]

for (var i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {
    newUL.appendChild(distance_to_li_map[distances[i]])
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it way slower also my original question was for the logic for finding the nearest state.

Comment: Also found that if i remove the div class on each li, the list scrolling is better. {<div class="lat" style="visibility:hidden">31.375626</div>
                <div class="long" style="visibility:hidden">-86.299592</div>}

Comment: Puzzled by "this code is way slower" this is very near to sorting described here http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/14-Sorting-Were-Doing-It-Wrong.html and proven to be more efficient than code you have in original example. Just see the link and try to adhere to recommendations as close as possible.